# How can I use a variable within a strings | grep command?

Tags: grep

I have a function which provides various information relevant to a file called `CODESFILE-00001.DAT`.

Within the function the following command works fine and returns the line containing `00202200USER`:

```
strings CODESFILE-00001.DAT | grep 00202200USER
```

However, I would like to use a variable instead of inserting `CODESFILE-00001.DAT` throughout the script so that each week when the `.DAT` version changes I only need to change the variable rather than all 7 entries within the script (I know find & replace works well but I just want to know if it is possible to have the file name set from a variable)

I have set the variable as `filename=CODESFILE-00001.DAT` and then tried the following without success:

```
strings $filename | grep 00202200USER 

strings “$filename” | grep 00202200USER
```

Comment: What does "without success" mean? Did you get an error? No output? Something else? There is no reason why your command wouldn't work, are you sure the variable is defined?

Comment: Your code example shows typographical quotes `“$filename”` which are different from the quoting expected by the shell (or several other programming languages) `"$filename"`. If you used a text document processing software like Microsoft Word or LibreOffice Writer for writing your code, it may automatically replace characters in a way incompatible with programming languages. Use a simple text editor or an editor designed for programming languages.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for your comment. without quotes the script just hangs and doesn't run any further commands. With the quotes it returns strings: '': No such file in place of where the result goes when I don't use the variable

Comment: @Bodo Thanks for your comment. I use Notepad++ as the editor. Out of interest I used '$filename' and this worked. However it doesn't work further into the script when as part of a filepath.

The command further down the script:

moves the current file, copies an archived version from a directory and puts it back (has to do this because post deployment the version delivered is configured differently and this saves time manually editing it as there's up to 19 instances to do)
command is install -C -m 660 - test_g /home/Archive/"CODESFILE-00001.DAT" /home/dir1/"CODESFILE-00001.DAT"

Comment: Don't use a Windows editor; that will wreck the line endings and prevent many things from working.

Comment: @tripleee unfortunately company restrictions mean we can only use Notepad or Notepad++ :(

Comment: I am fortunately unable to run Windows myself but I guess Notepad++ has options to save files with Unix line endings (LF only); make sure you do that, or postprocess the file with a tool like `dos2unix`

Comment: (That policy sounds bewildering, though; if you are using Linux anyway, why would the care if you used `vi` or Emacs inside that system? Let alone enforce the policy.)

Comment: Quick Duck Duck Going gets me https://www.atechtown.com/notepad-eol-conversion/

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the code line in your question. Please [edit] your question and show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where your script should be a single code block.

Answer (score 2):

Save this in a directory on your `PATH` and `chmod +x` the file.

```
#! /bin/sh -
: "${1?Syntax: $0 <file>}"
strings -- "$1" | grep '00202200USER'
```

Perhaps create more elaborate error checking and/or an option to specify a different pattern to `grep` for; but in essence, this is all there is to it.

The quotes around `$1` (and `$0`, and the `--` option delimiter) are important for robustness; but they need to be straight ASCII quotes (U+0022), not curly "typographer" quotes (U+201C, U+201D in your question).

Somewhat similarly, in a longer script, you could set

```
filename=${1-CODESFILE-00001.DAT}
```

to specify `CODESFILE-00001.DAT` as the default name of the file to scan, but allow the user to override the file name by adding an argument to the command line.

If you want to `grep` for multiple patterns in the `strings` output, you can say

```
strings -- "$filename" |
grep -e '00202200USER' \
     -e '1234SYSTEM' \
     -e '7890REAL'
```

to search for those three strings all at the same time (they will be output in the order they were found) or perhaps refactor to a simple Awk script if you want to sort by search string or otherwise postprocess the results. Here's a rough sketch.

```
strings -- "$filename" |
awk -v patterns='00202200USER;1234SYSTEM;7890REAL' '
   BEGIN { n=split(patterns, pat, ";") }
   { for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) if ($0 ~ pat[i]) hits[i] = hits[i] "\n\t" $0 }
   END { for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) print pat[i] hits[i] }'
```

Sample output:

```
00202200USER
    ick 00202200USER;1234SYSTEM;7890RE
1234SYSTEM
    ick 00202200USER;1234SYSTEM;7890RE
    foo 1234SYSTEM
7890REAL
    poo 7890REAL
    bah 7890REAL
```

(If there were no hits for a pattern, it will be printed anyway; if you don't want that, the fix should be fairly obvious.)

Comment: On a side-note, this is the first time I've come across that one-liner empty/null check. For those in my shoes, `:?` or `?` is built-in variable expansion check. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8889350

Comment: Yeah, some of the [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) are obscure.

Comment: @triplee Thanks for the comment. The script contains multiple functions which essentially do the same thing but for different services, therefore the values for the string and the grep are different.

As per your suggestion I'm going to try this to see if it works:
#!/bin/sh
: ${1?"Syntax: $0 <file>"}
strings "$1" | grep '00202200USER'
: ${2?"Syntax: $0 <file>"}
strings "$2" | grep '00202300USER'

Then use filename=${1-CODESFILE-00001.DAT} in the first function and filename=${2-CODESFILE-00005.DAT} in the second to see if that works.

Comment: Hmmm, so you want to search for different patterns in different files? Are the patterns static? Updated the answer with a quick and dirty Awk prototype.

Comment: @triplee I've managed to work it out thanks. without the need for the #!/bin/sh etc..

setting the variables as:
filename=CODESFILE-00001_ARCHIVE.DAT
filenamea=CODESFILE-00001.DAT
Then running with:
install -C -m 660 - test_g /home/Archive/'$CODESFILE-00001_ARCHIVE.DAT' /home/dir1/'$CODESFILE-00001.DAT'

Has done the trick :)

Many thanks for your help..

Comment: The single quotes in your command look wrong; do you really have a literal dollar sign in front of the file names?

Comment: Well spotted. It should have read $filenamearchive & $filename instead of $CODESFILE-00001_ARCHIVE.DAT & $CODESFILE-00001.DAT

Comment: Even then, single quotes prevent the variables from being expanded; you want double quotes instead.

Comment: They seem to be working fine for me..

Comment: That seems deeply mysterious, but you have not revealed the contents of the script or how exactly you are running it. In POSIX-compatible shells that's how quoting works.

Comment: I can't get the script off the vm and the script is way bigger than the number of characters allowed even if I could.. I've sorted it though which the main thing. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! If this solved your problem, please consider accepting it. Alternatively, you can post an answer of your own, and accept that. Accepting an answer helps future visitors by marking the question as resolved. See also [help.](/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -2):

It is much simpler:

```
#!/bin/sh
filename=CODESFILE-00001.DAT
pattern=00202200USER
grep $pattern $filename
```

You do not need `strings` since the `grep` can accept file name as a last parameter (do not afraid to use `man grep`).

You do not need quotes here, since your variable do not have spaces in them. But yes, you can do quotes too:

```
grep "$pattern" "$filename"
```

Comment: POSIXly, `grep` can only work on text data. Presumably the OP wants to extract text from some binary files.

Comment: Adding quotes are note to handle spaces. You *omit* quotes if you want split+glob. Here, you don't, so it doesn't make sense to omit quotes. Then, problems are with any character in the current value of `$IFS` (space, tab, newline) and with glob wildcard characters (like `*` which is common in regexps). You also need some `--` to handle values starting with `-` or use redirections. (`grep -e "$pattern" -- "$file"` or `grep -e "$pattern" < "$file"`, the latter working also for a file called `-`).

Comment: The file is a DAT file, so most likely binary which explains why the OP is using `strings`. In any case, even if `strings` weren't needed and you wanted to try with something like `grep -a` on greps that support it, this still doesn't answer the actual question of why `strings file.dat | grep foo` works but `strings $variable | grep foo` fails.

Comment: @White Owl Thanks for your comment. I've tried what you've suggest but get No such directory.. This isn't a major problem though ;)